# schema location error jboss-ejb3.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jboss

I found this [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3189) but seems that they were able to fix. I do not know what my error is but the error looks like the same with the error reported in the said issue.

Can someone give on how to resolve this a patch or a workaround, maybe ?

**jboss-ejb3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd 
               http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               version="3.1" impl-version="2.0">
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <s:security>
            <ejb-name>SecuredEjb</ejb-name>
            <s:security-domain>myJdbcSecurityDomain</s:security-domain>
            <s:run-as-principal>Admin</s:run-as-principal>
            <s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>false</s:missing-method-permissions-deny-access>
        </s:security>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

**Here is the error**
[image]

Thanks, Bell

Comment: Are you using the same version as the one mentioned in the JIRA? The JIRA already has a patch file attached to it. Why not just apply the patch and see if that helps? After downloading the source for your JBoss version, you can apply the patch, and re-build and test deploying your EJB.

Comment: @CoolBeans, thanks for the response. I am using wildfly 8.2.1 Final and eclipse Luna and based on JIRA the version reported was wildfly 8.0.0. Do I have to apply the patch with the current version that I have ?

Comment: There may be conflicts reported during the patch if the versions are not the same. Patch file is tied to line numbers of a source file typically, so you may have to resolve the conflicts manually if any such arise.